# How to make query to Google Analytics API using google-api-php-client

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, google-api-php-client

I tried use Google Analytics with [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)
I used version 1 (older, but it in [Analytics Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php#enable) and [API Client Library for PHP](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started#2-authorized-api-access-oauth-20) examples ) and version 2.

**"google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta"**:
Code:

```
    $service_account_email = 'pd*******@crucial-subset-******.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
    $key_file_location = \Yii::getAlias('@common/data/google-analitics/DEMO PROJECT-*******.p12');

    // Create and configure a new client object.
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("HelloAnalytics");
    $analytics = new \Google_Service_Analytics($client);

    // Read the generated client_secrets.p12 key.
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
    $cred = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_account_email,
        array(\Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY),
        $key
    );
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
    }
    $results = $analytics->data_ga->get(
        'ga:10****',
        '7daysAgo',
        'today',
        'ga:sessions');
```

Response:

```
Exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message  
'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A10****&start-date=7daysAgo
&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3Asessions: 
(403) User does not have any Google Analytics account.'
```

**google/apiclient:^2.0.0@RC**: 
Code:

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
    putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' .   \Yii::getAlias('@common/data/google-         analitics/DEMO PROJECT-************.json'));
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$user_to_impersonate = 'denis********@******.com';
$client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);
$scopes = [\Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY];
$client->setScopes($scopes);

if( $client->isAccessTokenExpired();) {
    $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}

$service = new \Google_Service_Analytics($client);
$results = $service->data_ga->get(
    'ga:******',
    '7daysAgo',
    'today',
    'ga:sessions');
```

Response:

```
Exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException' with message 'Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{
 "error": "unauthorized_client",
 "error_description": "Unauthorized client or scope in request."
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this guide, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php,it worked for me.